# Populating single property in Reform

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, rubygems, reform

I'm using `Reform` gem. Let's say I have some form to which I pass two dates as two separate attributes in params. Now in form I want to instantiate another attribute (which is also existing model attribute) called `interval` to calculate interval between these two dates and then save it to model.

```
# some_form.rb

class SomeForm < Reform::Form
   property: :starts_on
   property: :ends_on
   property: :interval
end
```

What is the best way to populate interval based on incoming dates, validate it and save it on model?

I tried different things, from overriding `validate` method and using `populator`/`prepopulator` options, but to no avail.

In best scenario, I would assume it would look like this:

```
class SomeForm < Reform::Form
   property: :starts_on
   property: :ends_on
   property: :interval, populate: :calculate_interval
end

def calcute_interval
    (starts_on..ends_on).count
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`populator` and `prepopulator` assume that the relevant properties are present in the incoming data. In your case, `interval` is not.

Do you want to validate the `interval` value? If not, calculate `interval` in an `Operation` step and don't involve `reform`.

If you want validation, your options are:

- a `populator` on either timestamp:

  ```
  # some_form.rb
  class SomeForm < Reform::Form
    property :starts_on
    property :ends_on, populator: ->(model:, fragment:, **) do
      self.interval = fragment - starts_on
      self.ends_on = fragment
    end
    property :interval, readable: false

    validation do
      required(:starts_on).filled(:time?)
      required(:ends_on).filled(:time?)
      required(:interval).filled(gt?: 2.hours) # or whatever value you like
    end
  end
  ```
- a custom [predicate](http://trailblazer.to/gems/reform/validation.html#dry-validation)+[rule](https://dry-rb.org/gems/dry-validation/0.13/high-level-rules/) combo:

  ```
  # some_form.rb
  class SomeForm < Reform::Form
    property :starts_on
    property :ends_on

    # NOTE: uses dry-validation v0.13 syntax
    validation do
        configure do
          config.messages_file = "/path/to/your/error_messages.yml"

          def gt?(interval, starts_on, ends_on)
            ends_on - starts_on > interval
          end
        end
      end

      required(:starts_on).filled(:time?)
      required(:ends_on).filled(:time?)
      rule(ends_on: [:ends_on, :starts_on]) do |ends_on, starts_on|
        ends_on.gt?(starts_on, 2.hours) # or whatever value you like
      end
    end
  end

  # error_messages.yml
  en:
    errors:
      rules:
        ends_on:
          gt?: "must be greater than starts_on by %{interval} seconds"
  ```